# How can I reference an Idris interface method from within the same interface declaration?

Tags: idris

I built a little TotalOrder class that has stronger proof properties than the regular Ord class. The problem is that these properties need to refer to each other in ways I'm not sure how to do, syntactically.

I need to reference my `lessThan` type in the other methods in the interface, but it seems to be getting treated as a regular (implicitly forall'd) variable.

```
module Order

%default total

public export
data Ordering : (t -> t -> Type) -> t -> t -> Type where
  LessThan : f x y -> Ordering f x y
  Equal : x = y -> Ordering f x y
  GreaterThan : f y x -> Ordering f x y

public export
interface TotalOrder a where
  lessThan : a -> a -> Type
  compare : (x, y : a) -> Ordering lessThan x y
  ltNeq : lessThan x y -> x = y -> Void
  ltNgt : lessThan x y -> lessThan y x -> Void

-- Implementation for Nats

compareNat : (x, y : Nat) -> Ordering LT x y
compareNat x y = ...

ltNeqNat : LT x y -> x = y -> Void
ltNeqNat lt eq = ... 

ltNgtNat : LT x y -> LT y x -> Void
ltNgtNat lt gt = ...

implementation TotalOrder Nat where
  lessThan = LT
  compare = compareNat -- THIS LINE REFUSES TO COMPILE
  ltNeq = ltNeqNat
  ltNgt = ltNgtNat
```

As best I can determine, the typechecker automatically assumes that the `lessThan`s in function position in `ltNeq` and `ltNgt` are the same as the `lessThan` declared in the interface, but the `lessThan` in argument position in `compare` is treated as a regular argument to `compare`, meaning that the type for the Nat implementation is

`compare : {lessThan : Nat -> Nat -> Type} -> (x, y : Nat) -> Ordering lessThan x y`

rather than

`compare : (x, y : Nat) -> Ordering LT x y`

and `compare = compareNat` no longer typechecks. When I run into this problem in top-level functions, fully-qualifying the name works, but I'm not sure what the fully-qualified name here would be, and the obvious ideas (`Order.lessThan`, `TotalOrder.lessThan`, `Order.TotalOrder.lessThan`) all get "no such variable"d.